# Resharper on VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Did anybody get resharper 4.5 working on V2010 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wait few days and try ReSharper for VS2010 - http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2009/05/preview-of-resharper-for-visual-studio-2010-coming-soon/

Answer (score 6):

Both of your answers are still wrong, he asked did you get R# 4.5 working... which the answer is NO. Visual Studio 2010 has a bran spanking new Text Editor written in WPF and MEF, so I very much doubt that R# 4.5 will support that :P

Answer (score 5):

Check out this:

Scientists hypothesize on existence of ReSharper for Visual Studio 2010. They argue pros and cons endlessly, bringing history to the table and even gamble around the odds if ReSharper can run in the new shining Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1.

You can know for sure, it runs! [Want to know when it will be running for you? Read on!](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2009/05/preview-of-resharper-for-visual-studio-2010-coming-soon/)

Comment: hmmm.. I post first with the same link and get downvoted? This site still baffles me.

Comment: I believe the general tone of your response is the issue.  I think the OP asks a legitimate question and does not need to be mocked for it.  That's just my 2c.

Comment: Its the text from the JetBrains site. I copied the first paragraph as an intro. I typically do this as a preview to the URL I post. Those aren't even my words.

Comment: Fair enough.  Do you believe that's clear by your post or can you see how it might be misinterpreted?

Comment: True. But since JetBrains has a sense of humor I just assumed that ReShaper users did too. :)

Comment: It's all good, I'll get you back to neutral. :)

Comment: :) Thats all I could ever want. At this rate I should hit 1000 rep by Aug or Sept.

Comment: @Robert - Tip! If you're quoting, use the blockquote notation in the answereditor. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can find ReSharper for Visual Studio 2010 Preview at the address below
http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+for+Visual+Studio+2010+%28Preview%29

Answer (score 0):

they have an interview with the resharper lead developer on http://www.how-to-code.com/ - apprantly you'll have to wait for resharper 5